# Slider and contact form only appears when the wordpress page is refreshed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a mysterious problem with my wordpress theme : HiTech from SMThemes. I nearly finished my website and didn't notice the problem until today : I realized that when I was accessing my (static) homepage from the menu, some of my plugins (slider and contact form) wouldn't display. But when I would refresh the page, my slider and my contact form would reappear.

The reason I didn't notice the problem is that the only page who had those plugins were on my homepage and that I never tried accessing my homepage from the menu until now... So after I realized that I tried adding sliders and contact forms on my other pages to see if the problem was only with the homepage. The same problem appeared : when accessing the page from the menu, the plugins wouldn't display. I checked the URL in the menu : the exact same than when I refresh the page...

I tried to compare the source code of the page refreshed and the one not displaying the plugins with firebug and I realized that there were empty DIV tags when the page wasn't refreshed (where the plugins were supposed to be)...

I found that really weird, I tried to use other plugins and in most of the cases the problem occured. Though I did end up finding plugins with which I didn't have to refresh the page I am really curious to know if someone knows where the problem comes from ?

Comment: maybe some plugins won't work well together. Can you reproduce the problem with ease? if Yes then try deactivating the plugins 1 by 1 and see which causes the problem. Then to replace the plugins functionality by coding it using some coding

Comment: I tried both plugins seperatly and even replacing them with other plugins but most of them produce the same problem... I think it's a theme's problem. But I m curious to know how it works when I refresh the page...

Comment: Maybe it is a javascript issue. Try loading the website while having your browser not load the javascript.